# Does the browser cache dynamic images?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

I am currently developing a web application which will be used by multiple clients, and I wish to display the clients logo on each page. The application is being developed using ASP.NET MVC3 and C#.

Normal convention suggests storing images in a database, but given that this image will be displayed on every page, I am concerned about the performance hit of doing this. If I store the image on the file system, the browser will cache the image and wont request it each time.

If I store the image in the database, will the browser also cache this, or will it call the function to request the image each time?

In such a case would I be better off storing the images on the hard disk of the server?

Comment: Used by different clients but with the same url? Sounds stupid, but I want to be sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (modern) browser doesn't know what the server did to store the image. If the URL is the same, the browser will just pull up the cached version unless it was explicitly told not to.

In some circumstances you may need to disable caching: `http://www.example.com/random-image` would probably serve up a different image each time it was accessed, and the browser would cache the first image served up.

Comment: Thanks, at the end of the day I guess the browser is only ever going to see the URL, in the format you specified, and it will then be up to the browser whether to re-load the image or not. I may look into Zootius's suggestion of setting the cache limits manually, but surely the browser would do this automatically?

Comment: Sorry, do what automatically? In the presence of HTTP cache headers, unless explicitly overridden, the browser does not treat graphics URLs any different to HTML URLs. The only thing that suggests to the browser what to do regarding caching is the cache headers in the HTTP. Use firebug / developer toolbar / fiddler / whatever to view the HTTP traffic when you call a page and you'll see the cache directives being set.

Comment: And by default, cache headers are *NOT* set for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Response.Cache headers appropriately in your dynamic image controller, and it won't matter that it comes from a dynamic source.

Check this post for an idea for setting caching using an MVC ActionFilter: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx. It also illustrates the headers you'll need to tweak.

Comment: Can you elaborate on which headers please?

Comment: Starter for 10: `Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);`

Answer (score -2):

Images are cached by their URLs. If URL has not changed since last load of the page, the image will be taken from cache.

Comment: The browser caches images based on the HTTP Cache headers sent by the web server. You may have noticed that tweaking the querystring "breaks" the cache and forces a refresh, but that is just a side-effect of IIS's standard caching policy. If the cache headers have been changed e.g. to `NoCache`, your assertion is not true.